# Import data as a cell array in a script in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, file, cell-array

I need to import data as a cell array to Matlab for many files and later on perform some operations to them. Is there any way I can import the data in a script to do it automatically instead of manually?

What I do manually is:

-Home > Import Data

-Choose .txt file

-As a cell array, 2 columns as text.

-Column delimiters: comma.

UPDATE:
Here a small piece of my .txt file:

```
/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/Matlab/Cascade1/training/positive/rawdata/d-0197.bmp, [329 210 50 51]
/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/Matlab/Cascade1/training/positive/rawdata/c-0044.bmp, [215 287 59 48]
/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/Matlab/Cascade1/training/positive/rawdata/e-0114.bmp, [298 244 46 45]
/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/Matlab/Cascade1/training/positive/rawdata/102.bmp, [243 126 163 143]
/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/Matlab/Cascade1/training/positive/rawdata/e-0120.bmp, [250 400 48 48]
```

Result: cell array with 2 text columns.

-The first column contains the paths to pictures:

```
'/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/Matlab/Cascade1/training/positive/rawdata/d-0197.bmp'
'/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/Matlab/Cascade1/training/positive/rawdata/c-0044.bmp'
'/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/Matlab/Cascade1/training/positive/rawdata/e-0114.bmp'
'/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/Matlab/Cascade1/training/positive/rawdata/102.bmp'
'/home/camroom/Dropbox/Internship/Matlab/Cascade1/training/positive/rawdata/e-0120.bmp'
```

-The second column contains the arrays as text:

```
' [329 210 50 51]'
' [215 287 59 48]'
' [298 244 46 45]'
' [243 126 163 143]'
' [250 400 48 48]'
```

Thank you

Comment: Sure there is. Post a small example with file contents and desired result of the import

Comment: Thanks, I just posted it. Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: I think this is enough to understand what you want. I can't take a look at it now. Maybe someone will. Also, I'll try to come back later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`importdata`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/importdata.html). This gives each line in a different cell. You then split each line using [`regexp`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/regexp.html) with the `'split'` option:

```
y = importdata('filename.txt');
y = regexp(y, ',', 'split'); %// or ', '
y = cat(1, y{:});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this-

```
T = readtable('fileName.txt','Delimiter',',','ReadVariableNames',false)
```

Comment: This generates a table, not a cell array. You would have to convert from table to cell array

Comment: Indeed I was looking for a cell array, but actually what I want as my final result is a structure, so I have to convert it anyway. If there is a way to obtain it as a structure directly, please share it. If not, this will do. Thank you